# Exported content providers can provide access to potentially sensitive data

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm using `ContentProvider` in my android application to share the database between the application. For sharing the database I need to add the provider access in `AndroidManifest.xml` like as follows:

```
<provider
android:name="Contentprovider"
android:authorities="umb.con.apps.vid" />
```

I added and implemented successfully but the warning message showing in the `<provider/>` tag like this "Exported content providers can provide access to potentially sensitive data". Will it cause any security problem in future?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you just want the content provider to be accessed internally from within your app, simply add

```
android:exported="false"
```

into the  node in the manifest.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html):

> false: The provider is not available to other applications. Set android:exported="false" to limit access to the provider to your applications. Only applications that have the same user ID (UID) as the provider will have access to it.

If, on the other hand, you really want to expose your data to other apps **but** you also have sensitive data in your data storage, remember that you can have more than one content provider and thus expose just the "public" one.

Comment: Also note that this is default if you are targeting 4.2 (API Level 17).

Comment: How exactly can you get ride of the warning if you wan't the provider to expose the data to any other app?

Comment: @pat8719 tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider" in manifest xml

Comment: Doing so (`android:exported="false"`), can we use it in the App Widget?

Comment: And if you add tools:ignore, remember to add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" to the manifest tag. Took me an hour to figure out why tools:ignore breaks the manifest file.

Comment: Thanx @fedepaol

Comment: What about if I want to allow access to my apps (i.e. signed with same cert, same developer) but not others? would it still need to be exported?

Answer (score 9):

Also if you are sure that you want to allow external access to your content provider and silence the warning add   `tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider"`

e.g.

```
<provider
tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider"
android:exported="true"
android:name="Contentprovider"
android:authorities="umb.con.apps.vid" />
```

Comment: Be sure to include the XML namespace prefix for `tools` in your `manifest` tag: `<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ...>`